# How to show existence and uniqueness of a SL problem with von Neumann BCs

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f\in C[0,1]$ be a continuous function and consider for $x\in(0,1)$ the Sturm-Liouvile problem $$ -u''(x)+x\cdot u(x)=f(x) \tag1$$ where $u'(0)=u'(1)=0.$

I need to show that for any $f\in C[0,1]$ there is a *unique* $u\in C^2[0,1]$ that satisfies (1).

Is there someone who knows a good book where I can find this result?

Comment: Hint: this question is probably related to the Airy function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function

Answer (score 3):

Uniqueness is easy, as your equation is linear.

Suppose $u,v$ are both solutions. Then it suffices to show that the function $w = u-v$, being their difference, vanishes everywhere. By subtracting the equations satisfied by $u$ and $v$, we get

$$ - w'' + x w = 0 $$

with boundary condition $w'(0) = w'(1) = 0$. Multiply your equation by $w$ and integrate, you get

$$ 0 = \int_0^1 w(-w'' + xw) \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 (w')^2 + xw^2 \mathrm{d}x $$

where we integrated by parts and used the boundary condition that $w'(0) = w'(1) = 0$. But as $x\in[0,1]$ and hence the integrand is manifestly non-negative, for the total integral to be 0 it is necessary that

$$ (w')^2 + xw^2 = 0 \implies (w')^2 = w^2 = 0 \implies w \equiv 0 $$

Existence can be obtained as an application of the variation principle. One can consult Gelfand and Fomin, *Calculus of Variations* for an exposition. The usual way would be to consider the Hilbert space $H$ of functions as the completion in the $H^1$ norm (both $u$ and $u'$ measured in $L^2$) of $C^1$ functions with vanishing derivatives at the boundary. One first show that on $H$ the functional $\int_0^1 (u')^2 + x u^2 - 2fu \mathrm{d}x$ is bounded from below, further more any local minimum must have bounded $H^1$ norm. This implies that we can find a bounded minimising sequence, which necessarily has a weakly converging subsequence which also converges strongly in $L^2$. With the observation that if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ then $\|u\| \leq \liminf \|u_n\|$ with equality only when $u_n\to u$, we see that the fact that the sequence is minimising implies that $u_n \to u$ strongly. Hence we have an $H^1$ weak solution. Using the Sobolev embedding theorems, we have that $H^1[0,1]\hookrightarrow C^0[0,1]$ and hence the solution must be continuous. Using the equation this implies the solution must be $C^2$.